# Moving a trained neural network to another device (Tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm new to neural networks and am creating one for a school project in Tensorflow. When training the model, my Mac froze because of the 560,000,000 parameters it had to run through, so I transferred the project to my Windows desktop which has a GPU. Can I transfer the trained model over to my Mac to make predictions? My project involves gunshot recognition, so I can't lug my desktop around to do the testing.

It took me about 6 hours to transfer the project from my Mac to desktop, so I'm hoping it's not as complicated as that was.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.